# PHP session not working in Safari, Webkit Nightly

Tags: php, session

My site has an index page, and that page checks if a php session is set with:

```
session_start();

$name = $_SESSION["name"];

if (!$name) {
  header('Location: name.php');
}
```

name.php has a simple form to set the name (no php), with an action of setName.php.
setName.php:

```
session_start();

$_SESSION["name"] = $_POST["name"];

header('Location: index.php');
```

In every browser except safari (and Webkit Nightly), the user sets their name, and is taken back to the index. However, in S(&WN) Submitting the name form loops back to the same page.

Cookies are enabled for all sites, and the session id is being set:
[image]

Edit: In case this makes any difference, my server is a macbook running MAMP with php 5.3.

If you want to try it yourself, the url is 121.73.150.105/questions, but it is often offline.

Comment: if you echo out $name and $_SESSION['name'] before the header() what shows up?  Anything?

Comment: Sorry, that was chrome. Nothing

Comment: Try to put die() directly after header() in setName.php

Comment: Like that: header('Location: index.php'); die();
Still loops back to name.php

Comment: I know that post is working fine

Comment: Is Safari reporting back the correct `SESSIONID`? Also, if you `print_r` `$_POST` and `$_SESSION`, are you seeing all your variables as expected?

Comment: Both browsers return: Post: Array ( [name] => MYNAME [submit] => Submit ), Session: Array ( [name] => MYNAME )

Comment: But when I go to index, safari dosent echo MYNAME (like chrome etc... do.)

Comment: Also, `print_r($_COOKIE)`, since the session ID is being handled by a cookie. My hunch is it's a problem with the way that the `SESSIONID` is being handled between your server -> Safari -> server; the server is storing the `$_SESSION['name']` data. One oddity I'm seeing in your image is the extra . at the beginning of the IP address. I'm not entirely sure, but I don't think that should be there. It's not in FF 3.6. But I don't know that that's causing your issue, since it should work only as an IP address wild card.

Comment: In safari $_COOKIE is empty...

Comment: That's probably what the issue is. Do you have cookies disabled on your Safari installation?

Comment: Nope. "Cookies are enabled for all sites" in Safari. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/182509/Screenshots/1~.png

Comment: Sessions work by storing a lookup id (SESSIONID) within the browser, using a cookie (a small text file). For each request, that cookie information is passed back to the server as part of the request header, hence allowing your server to "see" that request as belonging to that session. If Safari is not storing, acknowledging, or resending that cookie with the SESSIONID back to the server, it will not know that there is an active session belonging to that request.

Comment: I know that. Soooo....... how do I fix it?

Comment: Try clearing your cookies in Safari and restart the browser.

Comment: Another option would be to tell PHP to send the SESSIONID as part of the URL.

Comment: Didn't help :( I'm just installing Safari on my Windows PC to see if it helps.

Comment: I have Safari installed (on Win7), but I can't get it to run for some goofy reason. This after iTunes nagged me for the last six months to install it. :\

Comment: Try restarting PHP with ini.session.use-cookies = 0. This will force PHP to send the SID through the url. That may help prove it's a cookie issue in Safari. http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-cookies

Comment: Use-cookies did'nt help.

Comment: Use cookies =0 stops it working in ANY browser!

Comment: Sorry, I think you need to set ini.session.use-trans-sid = 1 as well. http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-trans-sid

Comment: You might also need to do `session_id($_GET['SID'])` as well. This shouldn't be a permanent solution either, only to see if Safari's cookies are the culprit.

Comment: Still works nowhere. The name isn't being set in the get string. Try it yourself

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317602/force-php-to-pass-the-sid-in-url-even-if-cookies-are-accepted-in-the-browser

Comment: Different prob, his is showing up in the GET string.

Comment: It's because the session ID is not being given to the browser. When you tell PHP not to use cookies, you have to then tell it to send the SID in the URL, or add it yourself, and then possibly tell PHP to reload that SESSIONID before session_start().

Comment: That's what I'm suggesting. See if it works in Safari if the SID is in the URL, and if it does, then there's an issue with cookies in Safari.

Comment: Speaking of which, I am using session_start(); at the beginning of every page...

Comment: There is no get string in any browser

Comment: Basically, bypass cookies, and if it works, then it's Safari's cookies (and possibly webkit, if you said you had the issue there, too).

Comment: I understand, but there is no get string, no session id in the url, in any browser

Comment: Ok, follow me here. Previously, you were using a cookie to send the SID to the server. This worked in all browsers except Safari (and webkit nightly). To TEST, I am suggesting removing COOKIES from the equation and using an SID within the URL instead to identify the session to PHP on your server. This may mean you have to do it manually, by putting the SID in yourself and then calling session_id($_GET['SID']) before session start().

Comment: You would add the SID to the URL on the server end (PHP used to do this for you... Not sure if they have removed this functionality).

Comment: Look here: http://jfcoder.com/test.php

Comment: Actually, you'll need to have session_id() after session_start(). Otherwise, there is no session to initialize an ID on.

Comment: Thanks. But that still loops back around to name.php

Comment: On your link, I'm not seeing an SID in your url. If it's not in your url, it won't know what session to use.

Comment: And you would need to persist it to each page.

Comment: I'm guessing also that you might consider reporting this as a bug to Apple, see what they say. I can't explain why sessions would work in all browsers, except Safari, except that Safari is messing up the session ID exchange somehow.

Comment: Fixed it in chrome, but still loops back around in safari. (because of if (!$name) {
  header('Location: name.php');
})

Comment: Maybe it's because I have an ip instead of a domain?

Comment: Well, if you have physical access to the computer it's running on, try http://localhost/questions/name.php on that computer.

Comment: I'm going to go to bed (it's late, early work...). I'm still thinking it has to be the way Safari is handling the session ID information, but I'm at a loss as to how to prove that at the moment. Either that, or it's something really silly like cookies in Safari are not clearing properly or something. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: Just for grins, give this a shot: http://jfcoder.com/test/index.php Here I am mimicking your code as you posted above and the html from the form in name.php. Do you still have the problem from my site? I only added one line (an echo on the name in index.php) and an exit() on the header redirect if $name isn't found in index.php.

Comment: Also, don't forget to turn cookies back on in your PHP ini file (or ini_set).

Comment: @Jared Farrish Works fine on your site!

Comment: @JJ56 - Create some test cases with as little code as possible, see if that works. If it does, go back to your code and comment out everything but the lines that make it work, and see if it works. If it does, start uncommenting code until you get to the spot where it starts failing. If it won't work even in your test case, then I suspect you may have a problem with how PHP is configured, or Safari is screwing up somehow. It's really hard to tell without some hands on work, though, just paring it down to the basics and stepping through it carefully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may not be the cause of your troubles, but here's what the PHP manual has to say about "Location":

> HTTP/1.1 requires an absolute URI as argument to » Location:  including the scheme, hostname and absolute path, but some clients accept relative URIs.

[PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Answer (score 0):

instead of:

`header('Location: index.php');`

try this:

`header('Location: index.php');
exit();`

After sending the location header, PHP will continue parsing, will still execute the rest of the page. This can mean your $_SESSION data isn't get saved by the time you need it. Forcing the exit should fix it.

Comment: Nope. That didn't work :( It stays on setName forever, and if I go to index, it takes me back to name.

Answer (score 0):

@JJ56, here's the code I had up that was working when you tried it.

**index.php**

```
<?php 

session_start();

$name = $_SESSION["name"];

if (!$name) {
  exit(header('Location: name.php'));
}

echo "Name is $name.";

?>
```

**name.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Questions Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="post" action="setName.php">
      <input type="text" name="name">
      <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
  </body>
<html>
```

**setName.php**

```
<?php 

session_start();

$_SESSION["name"] = $_POST["name"];

header('Location: index.php');

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sound like a problem with the PHPSESSID cookie.
For forms, links and iframes the this is solved by php's fallback mechanism: [url_rewriter.tags](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.url-rewriter.tags).

However, for (Location:) http headers this must be done manually.

```
header('Location: name.php?'.htmlspecialchars(SID));
```

Where php's SID constant is basically a `session_name().'='.session_id()`
See the ["PHP: Passing the Session ID"](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php) manual page for more info.

This doesn't only fixes the webkit bug, but also makes your website work in the other browsers when cookies are disabled.

Without passing the session_id in the header() the site relies on cookies so thats why `ini.session.use-cookies = 0` *(as suggested in the comments)* causes all browsers to stop working.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
if (!$name) {
  session_write_close();
  header('Location: name.php');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for your location, instead of "header('Location: name.php');"
try using the entire location address ex: 'Location: http://...name.php'
be sure to include the http://...ect part of the web address.

Answer (score 0):

> In every browser except safari (and Webkit Nightly), the user sets their name, and is taken back to the index. However, in S(&WN) Submitting the name form loops back to the same page.

Perhaps it's not your PHP, but just the HTML of your form. Would you mind posting it here?